# Trying to find value on the basis of latest date but getting error

Tags: excel

i am stuck and need your help. i have a spreadsheet in which the main columns are PAIRDID, PREFERRED, AUDIT DATE. what i want to do is for every pairid there could be n number of dates so my result column (f) should be for every PAIRDID it should show me the audit date of last preferred marked as Y . Attached is the screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TonKb.jpg)

Comment: maxifs not working for you? aggregate not working for you? max/index not working for you? cannot find a maxifs example?

Answer (score 0):

This will return the max value in column D for each unique PAIRDID IF they are marked as "Y" in column C. If the PAIRDID is marked as blanked, it will return a blank. Type this equation into F2 and then drag it down.

It is worth nothing that it will show you the same date on every duplicated PAIRDID that meets the criteria, but the date shown will always be the max.

```
=IF(AND(B:B=B2,C2="Y"),MAX(D:D),"")
```

Comment: big thanks! what if i need the result in column F for pairid against the last corresponding preferred being marked as Y

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking. It sounds like a different issue and should be posted (if you cannot find an answer from another post) as a new question if it is. if the above satisfies your original question you should mark this question as resolved OR you can edit your question.

Comment: In column F, with the above equation, all the values will be the same for each unique ID (if the corresponding value in C is "Y" that is) so it is not clear what you are trying to compare. The first ID that meets the criteria will be the same as the last same ID that meets this criteria.

Comment: I want the next audit date for last preferred marked as Y for a particular paidid . let say in the image the last preferred is marked Y against the audit date : 26-03-11 so it should pick the date just beneath it i.e. 18-11-11.